# Clarification with using std::, std::cout

Tags: c++

Can someone clarify what this means at the top of the file in C++?

```
using std::cout;
```

Thanks

Comment: and just don't forget to rtfm, http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that from then on in the code, when we type `cout` we mean `std::cout`

It injects the `cout` defined in namespace `std` into the current namespace. We use this over `using namespace std` as this is much more controlled; not every single `std` name will be injected with this statement.

Comment: but usually when i type "cout" in general it works fine. I have never really used std::cout, which is why I am wondering. Found this interesting and did not know what its purpose was

Comment: Did you type a `using namespace std;` before? Because this would do the same thing (Except for `endl` `swap` and tons of other stuff)

Comment: i always define it like this...
`using namespace std;` but i think i see it now

Answer (score 0):

It's a namespace declaration. Allows you to type out `cout` instead of `std::cout` and is generally preferred instead of `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 0):

The `using` declaration introduces the name `cout` to the global namespace as a synonym for `std::cout`.

Answer (score 0):

It is related with the "namespace" concept. In order to avoid name collisions (variables, classes, whatever, which have the same name in different files), you can put your code into a namespace as following:

```
namespace exampleNS
{
    class A { ... }

    void aFunction (...){ ... }
}
```

When you are inside namespace `exampleNS`, you can refer to class `A` using just the name, but from outside you need to write `exampleNS::A`.

If you want to save the verbosity of adding the namespace before a name that you use a lot (and you are sure does not collide with anything inside your current namespace), you can write that `using` statement.

Mostly all standard library utilities are inside `namespace std`, as for instance the variables `cout` and `cin`. In your case, your code is not inside the namespace `std`: you can choose between writing `std::cout` each time you want to print something, or write `using std::cout` at the beginning and then using it as `cout` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
using A::B
```

Where `A` is a namespace, means that accessibility of `B` does not require the prefixing of it's derivative. Note that this is only relative to the scope in which it is placed. If placed in a lower-level scope, it's function will not have any affect in the outer scope.